# C++ Reading From a .txt File + Binary Search + Sorting; Trouble with Classes

Tags: c++

So I need to read 10,000 numbers from an input.txt file, and then search to see if it is in the array, and if it isn't there, insert it and increment the frequency value in the frequency array. Then I need to sort the arrays in decreasing order by the frequency array. I know I am missing alot still... but my main question is found in main.cpp. When I reference TermTable.BinarySearch and TermTable.Sort, I get "Error: expected an identifier". Here is my main.cpp file. SO my biggest question is: Why can't I access the methods in the class TermTable??

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "TermTable.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
const int size = 10000;
int termArray[size];
int frequencyArray[size];
char * charArray = new char[size];
int position = 0;
ifstream fin("input.txt");
if (fin.is_open())
{
    cout << "Open" << endl;
    while (!fin.eof() && position < size){
        fin.get(charArray[position]);
        position++;
    }
    charArray[position - 1] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; charArray[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        termArray[i] = charArray[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; termArray[i] != '\0'; i++){
        int searchValue = termArray[i];
        TermTable.BinarySearch(int termArray, int size, int searchValue);
        if (position != -1){ frequencyArray[i] += 1; }
        else if (position == -1){ 
            frequencyArray[i] = 0;
        }

    }
    TermTable.Sort(int termArray, int size);
}
else 
{
    cout << "couldn't open" << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

And Here's my specification .cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "TermTable.h"
using namespace std;


int TermTable::BinarySearch(int array[], int size, int searchValue){
int first, last, middle, position; bool found; first = 0; last = size - 1; found = false; position = -1;
while (!found && first <=last)
{
    middle = (first + last) / 2; 
    if (array[middle] == searchValue)
    {
        found = true;
        position = middle;
    }
    else if (array[middle] > searchValue)
        last = middle - 1;
    else
        first = middle + 1;
}
return position;
}

void TermTable::Sort(int array[], int size){
int temp; bool swapOccurred;
do{
    swapOccurred = false;
    for (int count = (size-1); count > 0; count--)
    {
        if (array[count] < array[count - 1])
        {
            temp = array[count];
            array[count] = array[count - 1];
            array[count - 1] = temp;
            swapOccurred = true;
        }
    }
} while (swapOccurred);
}
```

And here is my class file.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//class specification
class TermTable {

public:
//constructor
TermTable();

//member functions
int BinarySearch(int array[],int size, int searchValue);
void Insert(int value);
void Sort(int array[],int size);

//destructor
~TermTable();

private:
//data
int currentAmount;

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things I found:

1. The methods `BinarySearch()` and `Sort()` are *member functions* of class `TermTable`, and not *static methods*. Hence, you need to instantiate `TermTable` and then use that object to call these methods.

In `main()`:

```
TermTable termTableObj;
termTableObj.BinarySearch(...);
...
termTableObj.Sort(...);
```

2. When calling a method, you just need to pass the variable name only, and not their types, like:

   ```
   TermTable termTableObj;
   termTableObj.BinarySearch(termArray, size, searchValue);
   termTableObj.Sort(termArray, size);
   ```

Comment: If you create class instance with the `new` operator, you must use class pointer `TermTable*`.

Comment: @binaryBaBa I think I did now. Cheeers.

Answer (score 0):

```
TermTable.BinarySearch(int termArray, int size, int searchValue);
        if (position != -1){ frequencyArray[i] += 1; }
        else if (position == -1){ 
            frequencyArray[i] = 0;
        }

    }
    TermTable.Sort(int termArray, int size);
```

I don't think you want the "int" when calling a function. When you define the function you need to define the parameter type but when calling a function I don't think you need it.
The compiler is expecting an identifier as opposed to a reserved word.